# How to preload sqflite data into variables before the build?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have my data in sqflite, I want my widget tree to build with the data stored in the db however, flutter builds the widgets before it retrieves the data from the db.

**I tried:** using future builder but in the full version of the app (not shown here), I have a linear progress bar animation that will trigger the entire widget tree rebuild when the animation is playing. This causes the future builder to show a circular progress bar "loading" in place of the widgets that were already built.

I figured that I don't need future builder since I only need to retrieve the data from the db to store them as variables.

The following code is a minimal representation of the problem that I am trying to solve, the code below throws an exception `NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.` because the db has not been fully loaded as yet. I want the data from the sqflite to be available for the widget tree build, how can I accomplish that?

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:phonica/sql/service.dart';

class Testing extends StatefulWidget {
  const Testing({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Testing> createState() => _TestingState();
}

class _TestingState extends State<Testing> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final _databaseService = DatabaseService();
  var data;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadData();
  }

  loadData() async {
    var cramModel = await _databaseService.readDatabaseTable();
    data = cramModel[1];
    return data;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.indigo[50],
      body: Container(
        child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
            return Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                  child: Text(
                    data["WORD_EN"], <--- EXCEPTION ERROR
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your loadData function you could setState data so it will rebuild the widget, when the data is loaded.

```
void loadData() async {

    var cramModel = await _databaseService.readDatabaseTable();
    
    setState(() {
       data = cramModel[1];
    });

    // return data; -> unecessary
}
```

In the build function where you want to access data, you should check if data is null or empty if so you could show an alternative (ProgressIndicator).

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.indigo[50],
    body: Container(
        child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                return Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                         Center(
                              child: data == null || data.isEmpty ? 
                                     CircularProgressIndicator() : 
                                     Text(data["WORD_EN"],),
                         ),
                    ],
                );
            },
        ),
    ),
);
```

If you would prefer using typed variables instead of var, you could also be able to check if data contains the key value pair.

Here is an example of what I mean.

```
Map<String, dynamic> data;
...
data == null || data.isEmpty ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Text(data.containsKey("WORD_EN") ? data["WORD_EN"] : "No data")
```